# how to stop the back button after the user press logout

Tags: php

login.php
I just want to prevent the user after the user logout and press the back button he will still logout... in the current state of my project after the user logout and press back button he will go back in the last page and still log in

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=MS932">
     <title>Login Page</title>
   <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

 <body>
<div id ="frm">
<form action="process.php" method="post" >
   <p>
          <label>Username:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="user" required/>
   </p>
   <p>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required/>
   </p>
   <p>

          <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Login"/>
   </p>


</form>
</div>
</body>
```

process.php

```
  <?php 
 $username = $_POST['user'];
 $password = $_POST['pass'];

  $username = stripcslashes($username);
  $password = stripcslashes($password);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("testproduct");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbluser where email = '$username' and  pass='$password'")or  die("Failed to query database".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if($row['email'] == $username && $row['pass'] == $password){
echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php');</script>";
 }else{

   echo "<script>alert('Login was unsuccessful, please check your username   and password')</script>";
   echo "<script>window.location.assign('login.php');</script>";
   return false;
 }
 ?>
```

logout.php

```
  <?php 
  session_start();
 session_destroy();
 $_SESSION = array();
 header("location: login.php");
  ?>
```

Comment: Check if the session array has keys present on the logout page. `if` keys exist, destroy session. If not, redirect back

Comment: I sure hope you're not going live with this, or is already live. Not with what you posted and on top of that, storing plain text passwords.

Comment: nope this proj. is more of a prototype

Comment: @JobJosephSanJuan So what's the update? We aren't hearing anything from you.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `session variable` on user login and destroy it on logout. Everytime you go to `index.php`, you check if that `session variable` exists or there is a `successful login`.

**http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php**

**process.php**

```
 <?php 
 session_start();

 $username = $_POST['user'];
 $password = $_POST['pass'];

  $username = stripcslashes($username);
  $password = stripcslashes($password);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("testproduct");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbluser where email = '$username' and  pass='$password'")or  die("Failed to query database".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if($row['email'] == $username && $row['pass'] == $password){
  $_SESSION['un'] = $username;
echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php');</script>";
 }else{

   echo "<script>alert('Login was unsuccessful, please check your username   and password')</script>";
   echo "<script>window.location.assign('login.php');</script>";
   return false;
 }
 ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['un'])){
   header("location:login.php");
  }

  ...

?>
```